# How is i==(20||10) evaluated?

Tags: c, logical-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int i=10;
   if(i==(20||10))
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
   return 0;
}
```

This gives the output *False*.

Please explain to me how does this program work?

Comment: if(i==(20||10)) won't work as you might expect

Comment: Do you think `10 == 1`?

Answer (score 2):

This line `if(i==(20||10))` always evaluates to `i==1` as `Alk` said in comments - `(20||10)` evaluates to `1`, hence when you compare `i == 1`, that is why you get `False` as the output. A non-Zero value in `C` implies true.

Read about [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Perhaps this is what you wanted:

```
int i=10;
if(i==20 || i == 10)
    printf("True");
else
    printf("False");
```

Comment: Also the OP's issue is not boolean-short-circuit issue.

Comment: @alk - Don't you think that in the expression `20||10` - the expression `10` does not need to be evaluated at all?

Comment: Sure, but this does not has an effect on the result.

Answer (score 1):

look at `if(i==(20||10))`. Due to the inner parentheses, `20||10` is evaluated first, yielding `1`. Then, variable `i`, whose value is `10` is compared to `1`, resulting `0`.

In C, and `0` stands for  `False`, while all non-zero values means `True`. So the condition comes to be `False`. Thus, "False" is printed.